# NodeJS+Express+SQL Server backend application Error : Incorrect Syntax near '83' , Incorrect Syntax near '68' etc

Tags: node.js, sql-server, express

In my application I get the following errors when I'm trying to reach GET, PUT, DELETE routes (tried POSTMAN and VSCode REST Server):

Error 1:

```
GET by ID : `Incorrect Syntax near '83'.`
```

Error 2:

```
GET ALL : `Incorrect Syntax near '83'.`
```

Error 3:

```
PUT : `Incorrect syntax near '85'.`
```

Error 4:

```
DELETE : `Incorrect syntax near '68'.`
```

I have googled the error but most of them are related to spacing errors in parameters in the SQL query but I have checked mine and the queries I have are all correct compared to those.

I suspect if this related to any SQL Server related encoding but not sure.

Below are some of my coding as a start to investigate:

`eventController.js`

```
'use strict';

const eventData = require('../data/events');

const getEvents = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const events = await eventData.getEvents();
        res.send(events);
    }catch (error) {
        res.status(400).send(error.message);
    }
}

const getEvent = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const eventId = req.params.id;
        const oneEvent = await eventData.getById(eventId);
        res.send(oneEvent)
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(400).send(error.message)
    }
}

const updateEvent = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const eventId = req.params.id;
        const data = req.body;
        const updated = await eventData.updateEvent(eventId, data);
        res.send(updated);
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(400).send(error.message)
    }
}

const deleteEvent = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const eventId = req.params.id;
        const deletedevent = await eventData.deleteEvent(eventId);
        res.send(deletedevent);
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(400).send(error.message)
    }
}

module.exports = {
    getEvents,
    getEvent,
    updateEvent,
    deleteEvent
}
```

`eventslist.sql`

```
SELECT [ord_type],
[ord_no],
[line_seq_no],
[lvl_no],
[cmt_type],
[cmt_seq_no],
[cmt],
[CMT_DOC_TYPE],
[EXTRA_1],
[extra_2],
[extra_3],
[extra_4],
[extra_5],
[extra_6],
[extra_7],
[extra_8],
[extra_9],
[extra_10],
[extra_11],
[extra_12],
[extra_13],
[extra_14],
[extra_15],
[FILLER_0001],
[ID],
[is_ext],
[RowVersion] 
FROM [100].[dbo].[OELINCMT_SQL]
```

`utils.js`

```
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs-extra');
const {join} = require('path');

const loadSqlQueries = async (folderName) => {
    const filePath = join(process.cwd(), 'data', folderName);
    const files = await fs.readdir(filePath);
    const sqlFiles = await files.filter(f => f.endsWith('.sql'));
    const queries = {};

    for (const sqlFile of sqlFiles) {
        const query = await fs.readFileSync(join(filePath, sqlFile));
        queries[sqlFile.replace(".sql", "")] = query
    }
    return queries;
}

module.exports = {
    loadSqlQueries
}
```

**UPDATE : Added data/events**

`index.js`

```
'use strict';

const utils = require('../utils');
const config = require('../../config');
const sql = require('mssql');

const getEvents = async () => {
    try {
        let pool = await sql.connect(config.sql);
        const sqlQueries = await utils.loadSqlQueries('events');
        const list = await pool.request().query(sqlQueries.eventslist);
        return list.recordset;
    } catch (error) {
        return error.message;
    }
}

const getById = async (eventId) => {
    try {
        let pool = await sql.connect(config.sql);
        const sqlQueries = await utils.loadSqlQueries('events');
        const oneEvent = await pool.request()
                        .input('eventId', sql.Char(8), eventId)
                        .query(sqlQueries.eventbyId);
        return oneEvent.recordset;
    } catch (error) {
        return error.message;
    }
}

const updateEvent = async (eventId, eventData) => {
    try {
        let pool = await sql.connect(config.sql);
        const sqlQueries = await utils.loadSqlQueries('events');
        const update = await pool.request()
                        .input('eventId', sql.Char(8), eventId)
                        .input('cmt', sql.NVarChar(4000), eventData.cmt)
                        .query(sqlQueries.updateEvent);
        return update.recordset;
    } catch (error) {
        return error.message
    }
}

const deleteEvent = async (eventId) => {
    try {
        let pool = await sql.connect(config.sql);
        const sqlQueries = await utils.loadSqlQueries('events');
        const deleted = await pool.request()
                        .input('eventId', sql.Char(8), eventId)
                        .query(sqlQueries.deleteEvent);
        return deleted.recordset;
    } catch (error) {
        return error.message
    }
}

module.exports = {
    getEvents,
    getById,
    updateEvent,
    deleteEvent
}
```

`eventbyId.sql`

```
SELECT [ord_type]
        ,[ord_no]
        ,[line_seq_no]
        ,[lvl_no]
        ,[cmt_type]
        ,[cmt_seq_no]
        ,[cmt]
        ,[CMT_DOC_TYPE]
        ,[EXTRA_1]
        ,[extra_2]
        ,[extra_3]
        ,[extra_4]
        ,[extra_5]
        ,[extra_6]
        ,[extra_7]
        ,[extra_8]
        ,[extra_9]
        ,[extra_10]
        ,[extra_11]
        ,[extra_12]
        ,[extra_13]
        ,[extra_14]
        ,[extra_15]
        ,[FILLER_0001]
        ,[ID]
        ,[is_ext]
        ,[RowVersion]
    FROM [100].[dbo].[OELINCMT_SQL]
    WHERE [ord_no] = @eventId
```

**Request for GET ALL via POSTMAN**
[image: GET ALL POSTMAN]

**Request for GET by ID via POSTMAN**
[image: GET by ID POSTMAN]

**Request for GET ALL via REST Server**
[image: GET ALL via REST SERVER]

**RAW Body of GET ALL request**
[image: RAW Body of GET ALL]

**RAW Body of GET by ID request**
[image: RAW Body of GET by ID]

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft In my `../data/events` folder all contains of the sql queries including the `index.js` file to define and export the events. I have added `index.js` and `eventbyId.sql` for reference

Comment: sound like the problem is in the xml or JSON request -- but you don't show that.  What do the requests to the service look like?

Comment: @Hogan just added the requests to the post via `POSTMAN`, `REST server` for some `ROUTES`. Please refer, Thank you!

Comment: These are the responses -- they look as expected based on your description, can we see the body (in RAW) of the requests?

Comment: @Hogan just added 2 more pics for the reference, Thanks!